# Static server nestjs + fastify problems with cache

Tags: static, nestjs, fastify

I have a static server setup with nestjs and fastify, but when I upload a new image it can't be seen if I don't shut down and restart the server. The rest works fine but not the new images, I thought it would be a cache thing but I haven't turned it off and it keeps happening.

I'm migrating express to fastify and the truth is there are many things that have strange behavior

```
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '../uploaders'),
      serveRoot: '/uploaders',
      renderPath: '*',
    }),
```

Turn off the cache, try to change the routes, add parameters to it